# Why the value of v is always either 27 (11011) or 28 (11100)?

Tags: signature, verify, ecrecover

Why the value of v is always either 27 (11011) or 28 (11100), and, how is it known wether it will be 27 or 28?

Comment: It is called recovery bit, and is used to recover the public key of the transaction signer. Here are some details https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/38351/ecdsa-v-r-s-what-is-v. Ethereum uses ECDSA signatures and there's a math trick to recover the sender so you save 33 bytes from the transaction.

Comment: With that math trick, v does not need to be known to verify a signature?

Comment: Yes, the public key recovery equation has two possible solutions (https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/18105/how-does-recovering-the-public-key-from-an-ecdsa-signature-work) and v is used to disambiguate between them.