# Go Ethereum "invalid signature recovery id" when recovery byte is >= 4

Tags: go-ethereum, cryptography, golang, keccak, ecdsa

I have a signed message that was generated by Metamask. It looks like this: `0x27876c5cc1be67e8313633ab0f72ace790886c88a664df1ca0b858c1834782002a0ae1e44fdb3fe7586eec431c115205a36a05bbd31c6c2bce04605825e91cfe1b` and the 65th byte is `27`. I know this because in my Go program I can retrieve the value:

```go
decodedMessage := hexutil.MustDecode(signedMessage)
decodedMessage[64] // 27
```

As far as I can tell, all Ethereum signed messages need to have the recovery bit as `27` or `28`. [Even the Go Ethereum library says so](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/496f05cf52f2b7f1baaa064eee49aea8ed604ec8/internal/ethapi/api.go#L512).

However, the problem is that when I try to use `crypto.SigToPub()` or `crypto.Ecrecover()`, I get an error that says **"invalid signature recovery id"**. I see exactly where this error is coming from ([here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/8a134014b4b370b4a3632e32a2fc8e84ee2b6947/crypto/secp256k1/secp256.go#L171-L179)), but I have no idea why it's doing this check. Here's the snippet I'm talking about:

```go
func checkSignature(sig []byte) error {
    if len(sig) != 65 {
        return ErrInvalidSignatureLen
    }
    if sig[64] >= 4 {                    // <-- This line is checking if the 65th byte is >= 4
        return ErrInvalidRecoveryID
    }
    return nil
}
```

I'm able to solve my problem by just setting the 65th byte to 0 `decodedMessage[64] = 0` and recover the public key, but I'm completely lost as to why this check is being done. Is the 65th byte not supposed to be 27 or 28? I can't find documentation mentioning anything about the 65th byte not being able to be higher than 3.

Comment: Instead of potentially duplicating, check my answer here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/113499/why-is-value-of-ecdsa-v-often-neither-27-nor-28/113505#113505 If anything is left unclear tell me, and I'll expand on it for you.

Comment: This answer might also help you : https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/38909/127657

Comment: @hroussille thanks for sharing this. My only outstanding question is: if EIP-155 claims both 27 and 28 are still valid, how-come the Go Ethereum library does not recognize that? Is this a mistake in the codebase? Or should I be making my code subtract 27 from the recid?

Comment: Okay, so pre EIP-155 (https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-155.md) the recovery ID was either 27 or 28 computed as {0,1} + 27. The true low level expected value is still 0 or 1, the 27 addition is just to identify it as part of the Ethereum network. Post EIP-155, you can use the new and safer scheme that requires the recovery ID to be encoded as {0,1} + CHAIN_ID * 2, the true low level expected value is still 0 or 1. Long story short, for your example, just subtract 27 from the 65th byte, the lower level implementation expects it between 0 and 3.

Comment: Here I found an example on pre EIP-155 transactions where you can see the substraction : https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/signer/core/signed_data.go#L289

Comment: And here a more generic example handling different types of tx (pre and post EIP-155) (https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/types/transaction.go#L201) where different substractions are used, but they are here nonetheless.

Comment: So to answer your question, you either use the higher level API which will handle that for you, or you provide the correct data to the lower level one, for the latter you do need to do this subtraction yourself.

Comment: Thanks for all this useful info @hroussille ! This question can be marked at duplicate unless you want to provide some of this info as your answer.